# Android SQLite result to Array

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite

I've been playing around with android sqlite and I noticed it uses a cursor. Is their a function that takes query as input and returns a 2D array for all results.

I come from php and its a lot more easy, but i can't find any similar function any where!

Comment: You really don't want to put the results of a (possibly very large) database query into an array on a device as memory-constrained as a smartphone. What do you want to do with the data? There most likely is a better approach.

Comment: i will be reading back and forth many times as i traverse each and every single row. it is an optimization type. and no the fetch result is very small. possibly 10 rows or at most 100

Answer (score 1):

No, the Cursor is what is used for all database query results. The Cursor object is beneficial to Java because it is a strongly-typed language. PHP uses dynamic weak typing which lends itself to that kind of SQL query response. Also there are memory considerations that a Cursor will solve by being able to see only one row of data at a time.

Comment: perhaps ur right, but sometimes i need to fetch whole query into an array and then traverse certain rows, depending on the algorithm

Comment: You can pull all the data you want, the point is that the Cursor helps you manage it.